# Import "django.core.management" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

Tags: python

Im totaly green in python dev and i stuck on the beginning on tutorial.
I bought course to quickly learn how to make REST API in Python with Django and DjangoRestFramework.
At first attempt i stuck at the moment, where i creating first model because of error:

> Import "django.db" could not be resolved from
> sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

I have a lot of issues with PyCharm with Anaconda on my M1 MacOs, so i moved on to Visual Studio Code with extenstions to create a new project, but im currently stuck on this command:

> python3 manage.py startapp sue_api

It causes a error:

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and
> available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to
> activate a virtual environment?

I've installed Django and DjangoRestFramework using requirements.txt and command:

> pip3 install -r requirements.txt

And all requirements are satisfied. So whats wrong there? Im in my created enviroment and have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error that you are getting indicates that Django is not installed yet. so first of all try `django-admin` command and see if the package is installed correctly.

if not then you have to install the package with pip or any package manager like poetry or pipenv or even install it directly from github page:

```
pip install Django
```

so check your `requirements.txt` and make sure django is there.

and also make sure you are using the same environment on pip3 and python3

Comment: (env) user@192 sue-rest-api % django-admin --version
4.2.3

Comment: requirements.txt
django==4.2.3
djangorestframework==3.14.0

Comment: @MuzealnaDotacja what ide are you using? how did you create virtual environment? are you sure python and pip command are using the same env? same version?

Comment: i dont know, im using pip3 and python3 commands, i set up my env with this command: python3 -m venv ~/env

Comment: (env) user@192 sue-rest-api % python3 --version
Python 3.11.4
(env) user@192 sue-rest-api % pip3 --version
pip 23.1.2 from /Users/user/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

Comment: as i said the python3 doesn't see django in its libraries, try again, remove the venv, create the venv with virtualenv package: `python3 -m virtualenv env` and make sure to activate it : `source venv/scripts/activate` and then install the packages with this command: `python3 -m pip install -r requriments.txt `

Comment: also try doing it without virtual environment as well

Comment: well, i did it outside venv and now it worked in venv.

Comment: Then you might not be using venv now, make sure everything is right. also create another shell when to make sure the enviromment is different